# M2M in lua or javascript

Tags: javascript, lua

for M2M application which is better among Javascript and Lua? 
everyone talks about LUA when it comes to M2M applications.i am aware of javascript very much.
so is it worth learning Lua and later implemnting to M2M applications instead of javascript?

Comment: Possible [Shark vs Gorilla](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)?

Comment: its machine to machine communication development application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript's advantage in M2M is that it does serialization and deserialization automatically with JSON. Although Javascript has some [foibles](http://wtfjs.com/), JSON is useful enough that it's widely used, even where Javascript is not.

Javascript's other advantage is that it's supported on anything that has a browser, so all desktops and smartphones, and has lots of features like TCP and UI.

Lua is in general a better language, and its VM is much smaller, so it can fit on embedded systems with less storage and memory, and there is a version called eLua which is even smaller. But one reason it's small is that it does not have much external functionality: you'd have to add serialization, TCP and UI yourself, or find libraries that suit. You might have to make more effort to port to some platforms, as I once did for Android, for example, where Javascript would have been easier.

Answer (score 0):

Lua is a better language than JavaScript in pretty much every way (aesthetic preference for C-like syntax not-withstanding), *and* it's smaller, faster, more easily embedded and extended. So given a choice between the two languages, purely on their technical merits, it's pretty much a no-brainer.

However, JavaScript is more widely known than Lua. If your customers and/or professionals in your industry (in particular, those who will be using your tool) already know JavaScript, that's not something you can disregard lightly.

That said, I worked on a distributed network testing tool which we made scriptable via TCL, just because the testers already knew it, and we regretted the decision for years. Should have used Lua.

In short, use Lua if you can. Use JavaScript if you must; it's not a terrible language, but Lua, bullet point for bullet point, is simply better.